# How to correct some spelling mistakes while there's a limitation: said edits must be at least 6 characters

Tags: support, editing

How to correct some spelling mistakes while there's a limitation that said

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can always find something else to correct - in this snippet I'd maybe change "the key of the receiving party"  or 'the used password" to the password they have used, and include that you've done the additional grammar fixes cause of the lameness filter. Eventually, once you've enough reputation, you can make even small edits directly.

Comment: however if you use the practice as above, most times you'll be editing more than a few characters.  It's very rare that I actually make small edits.

Comment: Very frequent situation: everythink is ok, except the code needs formatting. While formatting, many spaces/linebreaks adds, nevertheless "Edits must be at least 6 characters". Why do I have to edit a GOOD question text? I think it is more correct to put such edition into the reviewing queue.

Answer (score -7):

I use the html codes < strike> and < /strike> (without the spaces).

Added:
 
Since this is frown upon, I suppose you can add blank spaces and new lines (since they will be removed automatically).

Comment: Don't do that, please. There is a revision history for the purpose of finding out what changed. Striking out just distracts.

Comment: As I originally asked for an _easy_ way (for who made the correction), it should technically work.

Comment: @Al3n - I assume you want something that won't upset other people and where your edits will actually be approved.  I personally won't approve edits like LDC3 suggests. Find something else to correct, if you can't, that might be a signed the edit actually to minor.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. And I don't want to make more changes for change just because of static rule. I haven't made the correction.

Comment: @Al3n - It should be telling that you got two moderators telling you something very similar.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't try that. I was just wanting the change as less as possible to the original.

Comment: @Ramhound If you see the tags, wouldn't it be better to remove them and use the correction instead of cancelling the edit? After all, the need is to have 6 characters.

Comment: @LDC3 - One could.  But a minor edit is still a minor edit.